# Camel RabbitMQ Java DSL Setup

Tags: apache-camel, rabbitmq

I'm trying to get a Camel RabbitMQ integration working, and just printing out queue messages to console.

Using the RabbitMQ web interface I can see connections ARE made, when I start my camel instance.

I've created a direct exchange called "test" , and a queue called "test" and bound them together.

Then I'm using the RabbitMQ web interface to publish a message to the exchange.

Here is the camel code I'm using, but I'm not seeing anything come out to my console and i'm not seeing any message receipt acknowledgement on the camel side. Camel is also not showing any 'consumers' connected.

```
public class IntegrationRouteFromRabbitMQBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("IntegrationRouteFromRabbitMQBuilder Instantiated");
        from("rabbitmq://localhost/test?queue=test").to("stream:out");
    }

}
```

I'm doing anything glaringly wrong? Or is there anything else I can try to get it wired up? I've tried adding a routing key as well with no luck.

Thanks

**UPDATE** To set this up I used this pattern: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html which is the standalone launcher...

the only thing I'm doing is main.addRouteBuilder(new IntegrationRouteFromRabbitMQBuilder()); Which should set up the context and fire everything up, as I understand it.

```
    public void boot() throws Exception {
    // create a Main instance
    main = new Main();
    // enable hangup support so you can press ctrl + c to terminate the JVM
    main.enableHangupSupport();

    // add routes
    main.addRouteBuilder(new IntegrationRouteFromRabbitMQBuilder());

    // run until you terminate the JVM
    System.out.println("Starting Camel. Use ctrl + c to terminate the JVM.\n");

    main.run();
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Adding error log output

```
    17:05:09.886 [main] INFO  o.a.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[rabbitmq://localhost/test?exchangeType=fanout&queue=test&routingKey=test123]
17:05:09.886 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - RabbitMQConsumer] TRACE o.a.c.c.rabbitmq.RabbitMQConsumer - Creating connection...
17:05:09.886 [main] TRACE o.a.camel.support.ServiceSupport - Starting service
17:05:09.886 [main] TRACE org.apache.camel.util.EventHelper - Notification of event is disabled: Started route: route1
17:05:09.886 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.m.DefaultManagementLifecycleStrategy - Load performance statistics disabled
17:05:09.886 [main] INFO  o.a.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Total 1 routes, of which 1 is started.
17:05:09.887 [main] INFO  o.a.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.14.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.573 seconds
17:05:09.888 [main] TRACE org.apache.camel.util.EventHelper - Notification of event is disabled: Started CamelContext: camel-1
17:05:09.889 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - RabbitMQConsumer] DEBUG o.a.c.c.rabbitmq.RabbitMQConsumer - Created connection: amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/
17:05:09.889 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - RabbitMQConsumer] TRACE o.a.c.c.rabbitmq.RabbitMQConsumer - Creating channel...
17:05:09.889 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - RabbitMQConsumer] DEBUG o.a.c.c.rabbitmq.RabbitMQConsumer - Created channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1)
17:05:09.890 [pool-3-thread-3] TRACE o.a.c.u.c.CamelThreadFactory - Created thread[Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - RabbitMQConsumer] -> Thread[Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - RabbitMQConsumer,5,main]
```

Comment: can you post your camel context setup as well?

Comment: @stringy05 added the setup as well. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by not using the RabbitMQ interface to post a message.

I used the Send.java app from the RabbitMQ tutorials to publish a message that way I could make sure all the queues and exchanges we're correct, and it worked.